# Magento 2 How to add filter on render column with join

Tags: magento2.3

I want to add the filter on render column with join. I have 2 tables. first abcd that have cities name and second table have ids. That render column show name when coming id. that filter will show on grid of custom module. our main table have ids not name when I removed render then here city id's will show.
my code in grid.php

```
$this->addColumn(
                        '   city_id',
                        [
                            'header' => __('city Name'),
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'index' => 'city_id',
                            'renderer' => 'AB\DE\Block\Adminhtml\city\Grid\Renderer\cityName',
                            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'

                        ]
                    );
```

I want to add filter. when some one enter name and shoe that names.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom filter callback using the below code. in `_filterCollection` you will get the filter value based on that you need to filter your collection.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('city_id',
    [
        'header' => __('city Name'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'city_id',
        'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
        'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
        'renderer' => 'AB\DE\Block\Adminhtml\city\Grid\Renderer\cityName',
        'filter_condition_callback' => [$this,'_filterCollection']
    ]);
}

public function _filterCollection($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$column->getFilter()->getCondition()) {
        return;
    }

    $value = trim($column->getFilter()->getValue());

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
        // Your logic here, Do code
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this also but not working. even function also not call. I have check with die also.protected function _filterCollection($collection, $column)
{
    echo $value = trim($column->getFilter()->getValue());
die('ssssss');
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
        // Your logic here, Do code
    );

    //return $this;
}

Comment: can you try updated answer.

Comment: Yes but nothing happening.

Comment: Disable your cache and flush your cache then try. remove var/cache var/page_cache generated/code generated/metadata

Comment: Yes I have disabled and tried but no luck

Comment: I have magento 2.3.3

Comment: add public scope for _filterCollection() and try

Comment: public function _filterCollection($collection, $column) not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105676/discussion-between-rizwan-khan-and-hansraj-systematix).

Comment: Thanks now working